# How to get gender and country details from google sign in?

Tags: react-native, google-signin

In my react native project I've implemented Google signin functionality with firebase. When I signin using Google I get successfull response.

### GoogleSignInMethods

```
export const googleConfigure = () =>
  GoogleSignin.configure({
    webClientId: FIREBASE_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
    offlineAccess: true,
    forceCodeForRefreshToken: true,
    accountName: '',
  });

export const signIn = async () => {
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
    const info = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    console.warn({userInfo: info});
    // set user into state
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
      console.log('Sign in cancelled');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
      console.log('Sign in inprogress');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
      console.log('Play service not available in this device');
    } else {
      console.log('Something error happened', error);
    }
  }
};
```

### userInfo

```
user {
  email: "data comes here"
  familyName: "data comes here"
  givenName: "data comes here"
  id: "data comes here"
  name: "data comes here"
  photo: "data comes here"
}
```

for my project I need user's gender and country details. How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve users' gender using google sign in for react-native as the package does not have such functionality implemented. What you can do is call another google api with the token you received from calling the sign in function

```
await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
if (userInfo) {
  const { accessToken } = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    url: `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/${userInfo.user.id}?personFields=genders`,
  });
  console.log(response); // You should have the info here
}
```