# React Native Google Sign In User Birthday Access Problem

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I am trying to get user birthday when user is registered with Google Sign In and want to display his/her info in the profile page.

Google Sign In was implemented via firebase.
And then, I went to google developer console and made

1. Added People Apis and then go to OAuth consent screen
2. Select External
3. Added App domain, Authorized domains, Developer contact information
4. Added birthday scope
5. Added test users
6. Save and Back to Dashboard
7. Birthday info is set as public

The problem is still my test users cannot login to Google. It says "Access Denied. your app did not complete the google verification process. The app is currently being tested. Only approved test users can access the app."

I can only login with my developer account.
And when I logged in, in the console, I can see the birthday scope is added in scopes array. However the birthday info is still not in my user object.
I use "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.1" package.
Can someone help me please ?

Do I need to verify the domain/owner to be able to see birthday info ?
Or the package does not support this info ?
Why my test users cannot login even though I added them ?

My code is below

```
export const auth = {
  initGoogleSignIn: function () {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
      ],
      // scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'],
      webClientId: Config.GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
      offlineAccess: false,
    });
  },
};
```

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export const googleLogin = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true});
      const isSignedIn = await GoogleSignin.isSignedIn();
      if (isSignedIn && Platform.OS === 'android') {
        await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
      }

      const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const token = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
      dispatch(handleSocialSignup(COMMON.GOOGLE, token?.accessToken));

      // Create a Google credential with the token
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      // Sign-in the user with the credential
      const userSignIn = auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(userSignIn));
      userSignIn.then(user => Alert.alert(user)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('Cancelled by user');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        // play services not available or outdated
      } else {
        Sentry.captureException(error);
        Sentry.captureMessage(strings.common.undefinedError);
        console.log('some other error happened', error);
        dispatch(showSnackbar(strings.common.undefinedError));
      }
      return false;
    }
```

```
  const [googleUserName, setGoogleUserName] = useState('');
  const getGoogleUserName = async () => {
    const currentUser = await GoogleSignin.getCurrentUser();
    setGoogleUserName(currentUser);
    console.log('currentUser', currentUser);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getGoogleUserName();
  }, []);
  console.log('googleUserName', googleUserName);
```

Comment: I faced the same problem, check that your user has enough info (birthday and gender) filled in google

Comment: i filled them and they are all public as well @KirillNovikov. it is really weird :(

Comment: Any news? Facing same issue

Comment: unfortunately i could not find the solution @ElioRahi

Answer (score 0):

One would have to query the google's [people api](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) to get this info.

1. Enable people api in [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/people.googleapis.com/overview)
2. Get accessToken using `const {accessToken} = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();`
3. Make a request!!

```js
await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
if (userInfo) {
  const { accessToken } = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    url: `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/${userInfo.user.id}?personFields=genders,birthdays`,
  });
  console.log(response); // You should have the info here
}
```

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65560119/17446990) for the answer